# Why I can't get $this->post() value from JSON.stringify POST data

Tags: json, rest, codeigniter, post, stringify

I created a simple RESTful web services in CodeIgniter framework as an example project for my students.

I've got a problem with one of my API function as described below:

```php
  public function newmember_post()
  {
    $data = json_decode($this->post()[0], true);     // <-- point of my problem

    $ok = $this->guests_model->insertMember($data);

    if( $ok ) {
      $this->response( ['status'=>'OK', 'member_ID'=> $ok ], 200 );
    } else {
      $this->response( ['status'=>'Failed'], 500 );
    }
  }
```

When I try to get POST data items like

```php
  $nama = $this->post('nama);
  $alamat = $this->post('alamat');
  ...
```

I've got `null` value for all data items.

When I try to `var_dump( $this->post() )` , I've got this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(139) "{"nama":"Devi Chung","alamat":"Jl. Baji Ateka 20","kota":"Makassar","negara":"ID","kodepos":"90131","telepon":"871555","hp":"081234567890"}"
}

// it's a fake identity, no problem
```

POST data turns into an array, so, my solution to get POST data is like this

```
$data = json_decode($this->post()[0], true);
```

What's wrong with what I'm working on so I can't get POST data the normal way using `$this->post()`

---

At the front end, I'm using JavaScript Promise to do the API request for data POST

```js
const endpoint_url = 'http://my.services.web/api';

function newMemberSave(){
  var new_member = {
    'nama': document.getElementById("nama").value,
    'alamat': document.getElementById("alamat").value,
    'kota': document.getElementById("kota").value,
    'negara': document.getElementById("negara").value,
    'kodepos': document.getElementById("kodepos").value,
    'telepon': document.getElementById("telepon").value,
    'hp': document.getElementById("handphone").value
  }

  fetch( endpoint_url + "/guests/newmember", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(new_member)      // <-- point of my problem
  } )
    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if( data.status == 'OK' ){
        alert( "New member saved");
      } else {
        alert( "Save data failed, try again");
      }
    })
    .catch(error);
}
```

and to make it easier for me to handle API responses, I make these functions

```js
function status(response) {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log("Error : " + response.status);
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  }
}

function json(response) {
  return response.json();
}

function error(error) {
  console.log("Error : " + error);
}
```

If I'm not using `JSON.stringify`, POST data becomes null in the backend.

And also if I add a `Content-Type: application/json` header, I get an error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

you need to write "input" in between, try following

```
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama);
    $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
```

Comment: with `CI_Controller` that's right, we use `$this->input->post()` or `$this->input->get()`, 
but with `REST_Controller` we only use `$this->post()` or `$this->get()`. I've tried also and got `null` post data

Comment: what's the problem with $this->input->post() or $_POST?